# Preparing statement in Node js with SQLite3 for GET query

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite

On the API page, it is written that statements can be use to do a GET query ([Link to the API])[1](https://github.com/mapbox/node-sqlite3/wiki/API#statementgetparam--callback) but I have tried to use it and I can't have a good result (the row is always undefined)
Here is a sample of my code

```
var db = openDatabase();

db.serialize(function() {
    var stmt = db.prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE (?)=(?)");
    stmt.get(field,value,function(err,row){
        var callbckObj = null;

        if(row != undefined){
            callbckObj = new callbckObj(row);
        }
        callback(err, callbckObj);      
    });
    stmt.finalize();
});

db.close();
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Finally, the get statement can take only one parameter so the correct SQLITE query is :

```
db.serialize(function() {
    var stmt = db.prepare("SELECT * FROM table WHERE "+KEY_FIELD_NAME+"=(?)");
    stmt.get(fieldName,function(err,row){
        var callbckObj = null;

        if(row != undefined){
            callbckObj = new callbckObj(row);
        }
        callback(err, callbckObj);      
    });
    stmt.finalize();
});

db.close();
```